# Incomprehensible condition and incorrect operation of the function

Tags: php, ternary-operator

There is the following code ([demo here](https://ideone.com/v6ur5G)), the function (with recursion) go the matrix in a spiral collecting values:

```
function spiralmatrix($arr)
{
    return  $arr 
            ? array_merge(
                    array_shift($arr), 
                    spiralmatrix(array_reverse(transpose($arr)))
            )
            : $arr;
}

function transpose($arr)
{ 
    return $arr
            ? count($arr) == 1
                ? array_chunk($arr[0], 1) 
                : array_map(null, ...$arr)
            : $arr;
}
```

I understand that using multiple ternary expressions contributes to unreadable code. But there is more predominant sporting interest for code-Golf.

And so, to the question, is it possible to somehow change the condition to cut more characters? Can use any methods.

I would also like to ask, it is strange that the following works fine ([demo](https://ideone.com/v6ur5G)):

```
function transpose($arr)
{ 
    return $arr
            ? count($arr) == 1
                ? array_chunk($arr[0], 1) 
                : array_map(null, ...$arr)
            : $arr;
}
```

And the expression works a little wrong ([demo)](https://ideone.com/q5vsyu):

```
function transpose($arr)
{ 
    return count($arr) > 1 ? array_map(null, ...$arr) : $arr; 
}
```

Although, in separate tests (not in this function `spiralmatrix`) they show the same results what can is this problem? ([demo comparisons](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6468129b3d66f2b89a712cfe725cbc7c8cef961d)). Grateful for any help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your:

```
return count($arr) > 1 ? array_map(null, ...$arr) : $arr;
```

is that you are overlooking the truthy/falsey initial check:

```
return $arr
//      v----------------------------truthy----
        ? count($arr) == 1                    |
            ? array_chunk($arr[0], 1)         |
            : array_map(null, ...$arr)        |
        : $arr;                               |
//      ^----------------------------falsey----
```

Now, I'm not a code golfer, so I don't know if the spaces that you have posted "count" as characters.  I don't know if when it's "game time", everyone smashes their code down and you are simply doing us a favor in making the code readable.  That said here are a couple of ideas:

```
function transpose($arr)
{ 
    return $arr
            ? //count($arr) == 1
              //!isset($arr[1])                  <-- if spaces "count", this is shorter
              //!next($arr)                      <-- because no 0 in the arrays
              @!$arr[1]                  //      <-- the dirty stfu operator
                ? array_chunk($arr[0], 1) 
                : array_map(null, ...$arr)
            : $arr;
}
```

Now, I never use the stfu operator in my career, but if the gloves are off, maybe it's worth a look.  [Demo](https://3v4l.org/RSQ5j)

I'll keep staring at the code and chime in if anything strikes me.

Edit: I just realized `!next($arr)` works because there are no zeros in the sample data.

Actually, why am I playing with negation, flip everything around.  Duh!

```
function transpose($arr)
{ 
    return $arr
            ? //isset($arr[1])                  <-- if spaces "count", this is shorter
              //next($arr)                      <-- because no 0 in the arrays
              @$arr[1]                  //      <-- the dirty stfu operator
                ? array_map(null, ...$arr)
                : array_chunk($arr[0], 1) 
            : $arr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for a very detailed version of your answer!